# How to execute bundle command from Capistrano deploy script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I want to restart thin web servers after deploy. To do this I have the following code in `config/deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
desc 'Restart application...'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      within "#{current_path}" do
        execute "bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/app.yml restart"
      end
    end
  end
(...)
```

So I want to execute the `bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/app.yml restart` command in the current path folder.

This throws the error:

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host ...: bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/reboot.yml restart exit status: 127

*/EDIT First another error was shown because of a syntax error in the earlier code. This error was found by user [RAJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047207/raj) in his answer below*

Same error appears with this task:

```
task :restart do
on roles(:app) do
  within "#{current_path}" do
    execute :bundle, "thin -C /etc/thin/reboot.yml restart"
  end
end
```

How can I run bundle from deploy script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error message indicates, your are missing block for `within`.

Try this:

```
within "#{current_path}" do
  execute "bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/app.yml restart"
end
```

**instead of**

```
within "#{current_path}"
        execute "bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/app.yml restart"
```

Comment: Ah okay of course. But, now I get the `SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host ...: bundle exec thin -C /etc/thin/reboot.yml restart exit status: 127` again. I've updated the question.

Comment: @user2609980 You should not edit your question like you have done right now. Try to reset your question and then add edits further at the bottom of your question by mentioning your edits..

Comment: I thought the question would become too chaotic if I did that.

Comment: Yes you are right, as you have got answer for your original question, you should close this question and add new one. Add me to that, if you wish. I will try to help you